# WPF Validation & IDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

A note - the classes I have are `EntityObject` classes!

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "Name")
            {
                return "Hello error!";
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Validate: " + columnName);
            return null;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

XAML goes as follows:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding Foo.Bar}">
     <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I put a breakpoint and a `Console.Writeline` on the validation there - I get no breaks. The validation is not executed. Can anybody just press me against the place where my error lies?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a silly answer, but by default the binding calls the setter when `LostFocus` happens. Try doing that if you haven't done that.

If you want the error code to be triggered on every key press, Use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` inside the binding.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the 'Bar' class, then only the binding system will trigger the setter.

So your 'Name' property should most likely be.

```
public string Name 
    { 
          get{ return _name; } 
      set
      {
          _name = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); // Or the call might OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
    }
```

Comment: But as I mentioned above - both Foo and Bar and child classes of EntityObject class (which does notify OnPropertyChange).

Comment: I was actually thinking that thie EntityObject parent class can influence this somehow, as the IDataErrorInfo usually works fine.

Comment: @Jefim: what do you meant by parent/child classes? The Foo and Bar you presented doesn't inherit from anything. If you meant that Foo and Bar are declared as **inner** classes of some EntityObject-derived class, then this does not change anything at all. In C#, inner classes only affect public/protected/private visibility of the outerclass's members. They have no effect on the code/event/property/inheritance/etc behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the EntityObject class, nor can I find it in the .NET Framework documentation or a quick google search.

Anyway, what you need to do us use [NotifyOnValidationError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyonvalidationerror.aspx) as well:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Mode=TwoWay on your binding

Comment: I think that's WPF's default for `TextBox.Text` denendency property, so it wouldn't matter here.

Answer (score 1):

You should create local window resource containing Bar class reference and use its key to set StackPanel data context property. Also, don't forget to import its namespace in the window or user control.

Your XAML code should be like following:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.WindowName"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BarNamespace">  
<Window.Resources>
 <local:Bar x:Key="bar" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource bar}">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}"/>
</StackPanel> 
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make the methods implementing the IDataErrorInfo as public.

Comment: The OP is using explict interface implementation; visibility modifiers are prohibited when you do that.

Comment: and when using explicit interface implementation, `public` is not needed at all. That's still a valid implementation of the interface and will be seen by the interface clients.